# Redireccionar Virtual Host Apache

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

tengo dos virtual host en mi apache, ejemplo:

```
vhost.com
vhost.mx
```

cuando el usuario ingresa a vhost.com me tiene que dirigir a vhost.mx desde el index.php de vhost.com

```
<?php header("Location: vhost.mx"); ?>
```

cuando se ejecuta el index.php de vhost.com la URL queda de la siguiente forma: www.vhost.com/www.vhost.mx y esto me da un error de URL

¿Saben que se de debe que escribe las dos URL?

Answer (score 1):

Esta es la sintaxis correcta del archivo php:

```
<?php header("Location:http://www.vhost.mx"); ?>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo leer el artículo [Te he votado negativamente porque es solamente código.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882/)